# Substitute for Array.Sort in VBA

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba

We are adapting an existing piece of code from VB .Net to VBA, and we have the following issue:

VBA does not recognize sentences such as `Array.Resize`, `Array.Sort` and `Array.Reverse`.

What are the best workarounds for this in VBA?? We really need this!

Comment: is writing your own class in VBA an option?

Comment: If it is easy to do it, yes.

Our current situation is the following: we have a main (sub)routine that calls other user-defined subroutines and functions, all of them within the same kind of *workspace*. If you need further explanations, please tell us.

Comment: Well I think there is always a solution of this kind, to rewrite the methods no available in VBA. But it surely should be the last choice, there probably are ready solutions like in the answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

You can safely use the `System.Collections.ArrayList` class in VBA.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    Dim a As Object
    Set a = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    a.Add 30
    a.Add 20
    a.Add 10

    a.Sort

    For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
        Debug.Print a(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

That gives you `Sort` and `Reverse`. I'm not all that familiar with this deprecated class though, see if [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has anything that suits the bill for `Resize`.

Comment: Do you mean that the `System.Collections.ArrayList` is deprecated? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: If you're writing .net code, that type has been deprecated since the advent of generics in 2.0; you should be using `List<T>` instead, especially for value types, which incur boxing and unboxing every time they're added/fetched from an `ArrayList`. Generics don't work with COM interop though.

Comment: @Vicent [this code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/32618/23788) might be of interest then.